# Graphical view of gantt type schedule

Tags: graphics, drawing, scheduling, gantt-chart

Currently i work a lot with different type of scheduling-algorithms and i'm always in need of something easy and nice to output the created example-schedules for presentations.

Before coding it my self im wondering if such a tool is already developed?

It should, as a minimum, take as input a CPU (Y-coordinate) and a start and duration time (X-coordinate) and preferbly produce HTML, Latex, PDF or similar. (A generic Gantt chart drawer should be sufficient)

It can either be a standalone tool that can be called with a task-set consisting of the three parameters - or able to interface with either C/C++ or Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using JFreeChart. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at GraphViz (graphviz.org) - we've used it with success for showing relationships between things, and there's PERL example of using it for GANTT charts (though I haven't used that myself) here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=68941

Comment: I dont think it is sufficient - it lacks the ability to put a start time instead of describing the relations as dependencies. But thanks anyway

Comment: That Perl script doesn't use Graphviz. It only mentions Graphviz in a TODO list.